# Temporary lock windows (re)size in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I would like to lock the resize functionality in some cases in my application, to do so I tried to databind the property and don't permit to change it in some condition, but without success.

Is there a way to do so?

Here is my unsuccessful try: 
XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="namespace.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Test" MinHeight="300" MinWidth="600" Icon="Icon.ico"
    Height="{Binding WindowsHeight, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="{Binding WindowsWidth, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

ViewModel:

```
    private int _windowsHeight = 600;
    private int _windowsWidth = 900;

    public int WindowsHeight
    {
        get { return _windowsHeight; }
        set
        {
            if (_windowsHeight == value) return;

            if (ResizeAvailable) _windowsHeight = value;

            OnPropertyChanged("WindowsHeight");
        }
    }

    public int WindowsWidth
    {
        get { return _windowsWidth; }
        set
        {
            if (_windowsWidth == value) return;

            if (ResizeAvailable) _windowsWidth = value;

            OnPropertyChanged("WindowsWidth");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the size of the window when you start your app?

Comment: 600 by 900, defined by _windowsHeight and _windowsWidth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just set the resize mode to NoResize?

[Window.ResizeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.resizemode(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
this.ResizeMode = System.Windows.ResizeMode.NoResize;
```

Comment: ResizeMode cannot change on runtime.

Comment: That is odd.  If it cannot be changed then why would it even have a set?  Do you mean it cannot be bound?

Comment: @NicoC - You can bind `ResizeMode` with bool in your ViewModel and have converter in place to convert value from bool to ResizeMode enum.

Comment: @NicoC - And it's false statement that ResizeMode cannot be changed at runtime. What makes you think so?

Comment: I just tested and I was able to assign ResizeMode run time.  It has a set.

Comment: When I tried, only the first value was taken into account, when I changed it after during runtime, the windows didn't change.

Comment: How you change it? Can you update question with that approach?

Comment: What do you mean "first value"? There is no second. Just set the ResizeMode.

Comment: My bad.. my first test with ResizeMode didn't worked due to an error in my MVVM... 
Problem solved! Thanks everyone!